The almost product structure of the cartesian square of a smooth manifold
I suspect that the cartesian square of a manifold $M$ admits a "canonical" almost product structure, that is, a smooth $(1,1)$-tensor on $M\times M$ whose square is the identity. But I need help proving this.
First attempt
Following the idea of this post, I fix an atlas $\mathcal A=((U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha))$ of $M$, and I consider the chart $(U_{\alpha\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha\alpha})$. This chart trivialises the vector bundle $\tau_{M\times M}\colon T(M\times M)\to M\times M$, hence $\tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha})$ is diffeomorphic to $U_{\alpha\alpha}\times \mathbb R^{2d}$ via a diffeomorphism:
$$\Phi_\alpha\colon \tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha})\to U_{\alpha\alpha}\times \mathbb R^{2d}\,.$$
I can exploit $\Phi_\alpha$ to transfer the almost product structure of $\mathbb R^{2d}$:
$$
A_c\colon (a,b)\in \mathbb R^{2d}\mapsto (b,a)\in \mathbb R^{2d}
$$
to $\tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha})$. Then, I define:
$$
A_\alpha:=\Phi_\alpha^{-1}\circ (id_{U_{\alpha\alpha}}\times A_c)\circ \Phi_\alpha\,.
$$
Now, I want to glue all these maps $(A_\alpha)$ to a global one. This is possible if and only if for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ agree on the intersection of their domains. A simple calculation proves:
$$
A_\alpha=A_\beta \text{ on } \tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta}) \iff (\Phi_\beta\circ \Phi_\alpha^{-1})\circ (id_{U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta}}\times A_c)=(id_{U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta}}\times A_c)\circ (\Phi_\beta\circ \Phi_\alpha^{-1})
$$
Recall that:
$$
(\Phi_\beta\circ \Phi_\alpha^{-1})((m,n),(a,b))=((m,n),t_{(m,n)}^{\alpha,\beta}(a,b))
$$
where for any $(m,n)\in U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta}$, $t_{(m,n)}^{\alpha,\beta}$ is the Jacobina matrix of $\varphi_{\beta\beta}\circ \varphi_{\alpha\alpha}^{-1}$ at $\varphi_{\alpha\alpha}(m,n)$. Thus, the glueing condition holds if and only if for any $\alpha,\beta$, and $(m,n)\in U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta}$, $t_{m,n}^{\alpha,\beta}$ commutes with $A_c$. Unfortunately, this is not the case!
Second attempt The idea is very close to the previous one and in the same spirit as the answer to the post. Associated with any chart $(U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha}=(x_\alpha^j)_{j=1}^d)$, I can define the following map $A_\alpha\colon \tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha})\colon \tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha})$:
$$
A_\alpha((m,n),(v,w))=A_\alpha\bigg((m,n),\bigg(v^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_m,w^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_n\bigg)\bigg)=\bigg((m,n),\bigg(w^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_m,v^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_n\bigg)\bigg)
$$
where $(v_\alpha^i)_{i=1}^d$ is the coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to the basis associated with the chart $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$.
This map should extend to a smooth map $A\colon T(M\times M)\to T(M\times M)$ since for any $((m,n),(v,w))\in \tau_{M\times M}^{-1}(U_{\alpha\alpha}\cap U_{\beta\beta})$:
$$
v^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_n=v^j_\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\beta^j}\bigg|_n \qquad w^i_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha^i}\bigg|_m=w^j_\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\beta^j}\bigg|_m
$$
Doubts and questions Did I make some mistakes in my attempts? These attempts seem very similar, but only one works, and I don't understand why. Are there other ways of defining almost product structure on $M\times M$, if any?
